# FMX Component style not showing correctly in IDE

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Below are the sources to a very simple FMX component that simply inherits from a TCustomEdit but with a different Style. What I am going for is to have two buttons on the Windows version of the component and no buttons on the Android component.

When I compile the sources before and run a program with the component, both devices show the components as expected. Windows shows the two buttons, Android doesn't display the buttons.

My problem is, during design time in the IDE, setting the "Style" drop down to Android, the component is displayed using the Windows version. If I "edit the default style" when the Android style is selected, it shows the Edit "background" with a sourcelookup of "Windows 10 Desktopstyle.png", not "AndroidL Lightstyle.png" but also includes the buttons with a sourcelookup of "AndroidL Lightstyle.png".

My assumption is I am missing something is my component design that tells the IDE which version of style to use. Any idea what that is? FYI: this is a very simple component that shows the problem. My more complicated component has the same problem.

```
unit RHEdit;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.Edit, FMX.Controls.Model;

type
  TRHEdit = class(TCustomEdit)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    function GetStyleObject(const Clone: Boolean): TFmxObject; override;
    function DefinePresentationName: string; override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  published
    property Text;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

{$IFDEF ANDROID}
  {$R RHEdit_android.res}
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  {$R RHEdit_win.res}
{$ENDIF}

uses System.Types, FMX.Styles;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TRHEdit]);
end;

{ TRHEdit }

function TRHEdit.DefinePresentationName: string;
begin
  Result := 'RHEdit-' + GetPresentationSuffix;
end;

function TRHEdit.GetStyleObject(const Clone: Boolean): TFmxObject;
var
  style: string;
begin
  style := 'rheditstyle';
  if (StyleLookup = '') then
    Result:= TStyleStreaming.LoadFromResource(HInstance, Style, RT_RCDATA)
  else
    Result := inherited GetStyleObject(Clone);
end;

end.
```

RHEdit_android.rc

```
RHEditStyle RCDATA "RHEdit_android.style"
```

RHEdit_win.rc

```
RHEditStyle RCDATA "RHEdit_win.style"
```

RHEdit_android.style

```
  object TLayout
    StyleName = 'rheditstyle'
    TabOrder = 12
    FixedHeight = 32
    object TActiveStyleObject
      StyleName = 'background'
      Align = Contents
      SourceLookup = 'AndroidL Lightstyle.png'
      ActiveTrigger = Focused
      ActiveLink = <
        item
          CapInsets.Left = 4.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Right = 4.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Left = 94.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Top = 63.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Right = 127.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Bottom = 95.000000000000000000
        end
        item
          CapInsets.Left = 6.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Right = 6.000000000000000000
          Scale = 1.500000000000000000
          SourceRect.Left = 157.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Top = 95.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Right = 206.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Bottom = 143.000000000000000000
        end
        item
          CapInsets.Left = 8.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Right = 8.000000000000000000
          Scale = 2.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Left = 187.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Top = 122.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Right = 253.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Bottom = 186.000000000000000000
        end
        item
          CapInsets.Left = 12.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Right = 12.000000000000000000
          Scale = 3.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Left = 337.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Top = 190.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Right = 436.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Bottom = 286.000000000000000000
        end>
      SourceLink = <
        item
          CapInsets.Left = 4.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Right = 4.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Left = 94.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Top = 30.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Right = 127.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Bottom = 62.000000000000000000
        end
        item
          CapInsets.Left = 6.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Right = 6.000000000000000000
          Scale = 1.500000000000000000
          SourceRect.Left = 157.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Top = 45.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Right = 206.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Bottom = 93.000000000000000000
        end
        item
          CapInsets.Left = 8.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Right = 8.000000000000000000
          Scale = 2.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Left = 187.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Top = 57.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Right = 253.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Bottom = 121.000000000000000000
        end
        item
          CapInsets.Left = 12.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Right = 12.000000000000000000
          Scale = 3.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Left = 337.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Top = 93.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Right = 436.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Bottom = 189.000000000000000000
        end>
      TouchAnimation.Link = <>
    end
    object TLayout
      StyleName = 'content'
      Align = Client
      Locked = True
      Margins.Left = 32.000000000000000000
      Margins.Top = 4.000000000000000000
      Margins.Right = 32.000000000000000000
      Margins.Bottom = 4.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 0.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 42.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
    end
    object TColorObject
      StyleName = 'caretcolor'
      Color = xFF222222
    end
    object TBrushObject
      StyleName = 'foreground'
      Brush.Color = xFF222222
    end
    object TBrushObject
      StyleName = 'selection'
      Brush.Color = x7F33B5E5
    end
    object TFontObject
      StyleName = 'font'
      Font.Size = 18.000000000000000000
    end
  end
```

RHEdit_win.style

```
object TLayout
    StyleName = 'rheditstyle'
    TabOrder = 16
    object TActiveStyleObject
      StyleName = 'background'
      Align = Contents
      SourceLookup = 'Windows 10 Desktopstyle.png'
      ActiveTrigger = Focused
      ActiveLink = <
        item
          CapInsets.Left = 7.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Top = 7.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Right = 7.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Bottom = 7.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Left = 266.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Top = 81.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Right = 305.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Bottom = 110.000000000000000000
        end
        item
          CapInsets.Left = 10.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Top = 10.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Right = 10.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Bottom = 10.000000000000000000
          Scale = 1.500000000000000000
          SourceRect.Left = 399.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Top = 121.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Right = 457.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Bottom = 165.000000000000000000
        end
        item
          CapInsets.Left = 14.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Top = 14.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Right = 14.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Bottom = 14.000000000000000000
          Scale = 2.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Left = 532.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Top = 162.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Right = 610.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Bottom = 220.000000000000000000
        end>
      SourceLink = <
        item
          CapInsets.Left = 7.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Top = 7.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Right = 7.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Bottom = 7.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Left = 225.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Top = 81.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Right = 264.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Bottom = 110.000000000000000000
        end
        item
          CapInsets.Left = 10.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Top = 10.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Right = 10.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Bottom = 10.000000000000000000
          Scale = 1.500000000000000000
          SourceRect.Left = 337.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Top = 121.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Right = 396.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Bottom = 165.000000000000000000
        end
        item
          CapInsets.Left = 14.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Top = 14.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Right = 14.000000000000000000
          CapInsets.Bottom = 14.000000000000000000
          Scale = 2.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Left = 450.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Top = 162.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Right = 528.000000000000000000
          SourceRect.Bottom = 220.000000000000000000
        end>
      TouchAnimation.Link = <>
    end
    object TLayout
      StyleName = 'content'
      Align = Client
      Locked = True
      Margins.Left = 21.000000000000000000
      Margins.Top = 4.000000000000000000
      Margins.Right = 21.000000000000000000
      Margins.Bottom = 4.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 0.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 42.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
    end
    object TButton
      StyleName = 'minusbutton'
      Align = Left
      CanFocus = False
      Cursor = crArrow
      Margins.Left = 2.000000000000000000
      Margins.Top = 2.000000000000000000
      Margins.Right = 2.000000000000000000
      Margins.Bottom = 2.000000000000000000
      Position.X = 2.000000000000000000
      Position.Y = 2.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 20.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 46.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      StyleLookup = 'spinbottombutton'
    end
    object TButton
      StyleName = 'plusbutton'
      Align = Right
      CanFocus = False
      Cursor = crArrow
      Margins.Left = 2.000000000000000000
      Margins.Top = 2.000000000000000000
      Margins.Right = 2.000000000000000000
      Margins.Bottom = 2.000000000000000000
      Position.X = 28.000000000000000000
      Position.Y = 2.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 20.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 46.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      StyleLookup = 'spintopbutton'
    end
    object TBrushObject
      StyleName = 'foreground'
      Brush.Color = claBlack
    end
    object TBrushObject
      StyleName = 'selection'
      Brush.Color = x7F2A96FF
    end
    object TFontObject
      StyleName = 'font'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Anything compiled for design time will be for the Windows platform as that is what the IDE runs in. The IFDEFs checking the platform work fine at compile time. For in the IDE try checking the base style (DesignerMasterStyle) of the form and load your custom style based off that.

Comment: Where do I find the base style (DesignerMasterStyle) setting in the IDE? Note: tried to add two pictures of the IDE showing the form Style set to Android and Windows, but images did not show after the edit.

Comment: DesignerMasterStyle is a form property (view form as source) that is modified by the Style dropdown along the top of the form designer but is not visible in the Object Inspector.

Comment: OK, found the setting. It changes from 0 to 3 depending on what platform is selected in the IDE Style drop down for the form. Can you give me an example on how to use that within my component so it loads the correct custom style when that value is changed within the IDE for the form?